# Calculate peek and average timestamps per minute in ClickHouse

Tags: statistics, average, clickhouse

I have log entries in ClickHouse database, each log has a timestamp. I need to calculate two numbers:

- Average of logs per minute
- Peek values of logs per minute

```
timestamp                      | entry   |
-------------------------------|---------|
2022-03-08T22:28:02.177113916Z | message |
```

To solve this right now I created a simple Python script to analyze downloaded logs, but this doesn't work with actual amount of data, only small slice which I can download.

Can I calculate just by running query without downloading anything locally?

Answer (score 2):

Try this query:

```sql
SELECT avg(c) average_count, max(c) peak_count
FROM (
    SELECT count() c
    FROM logs
    /* WHERE timestamp >= 'time1' AND timestamp < 'time2' */
    GROUP BY toStartOfMinute(timestamp)
    )
```